# Why does magento2 display errors mostly related to core instead of the custom module files where core is extended?

Tags: magento2

When we extend a core module/controller, say loginPost, and if some error occurs, why does Magento2 show most core level errors,and some times a single line of our custom extended file?

Can somebody here answer in detail.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that when you change some functionality, your new class still extends the original core class.
In this case, if a (public or protected) method is called from your class and that class does not override the core method, the original method is called.
If that original method has an error the debug back trace will obviously report it in the core class.
This is not a magento specific case. It is how php works.
If the call to a core method is done from your own class, then you will get in the debug trace a line with your class in it.